# Making a user's message a variable on reply

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I have been trying to make a discord bot in python and it needs a very simple feature that I cant seem to get working. With the on_message function I have been trying to get the bot to reply when the user sends a message saying "authenticate" with a response of "please enter your API key", what I want to happen afterwards is that user's next message becomes the variable called 'key', I haven't been able to make sense of the documentation of rewrite enough to get this to work.

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith("authenticate"):
        channel = message.channel
        await channel.send("Please enter your API key")
        key = await channel.send("User sends API key?")

    await client.process_commands(message)
```

Comment: You should instruct the user to send the message as `authenticate <your_api_key>` then to get the api_key do `message_parts = message.content.split(' ')` `if len(message_parts) == 2: api_key = message_parts[1]; else: await channel.send("Please use the command, 'authenticate your_api_key'")`

Comment: @Tim This I could do much easier without the on_message function with an async def that cas ctx, *, message or something as it's parameters, The idea is that there is more to the authentication than the api key and it will look bulky if I do a command like "authenticate <key1> <key2> <key3>" etc, so what I want to do is have the user say authenticate or similar, then the bot will ask the user to enter the api key, the bot will then store that as a variable and ask the user for the next key, store that as a variable , so on so forth